# Why does Oracle open cursors by JDBC inserts?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, insert, cursor, odbc

I use an Oracle Database with JDBC and execute INSERTs on a connection. For each insert I create a new `Statement`.

After much inserts (>1000), the error `ORA-01000` occurs, meaning that Oracle has open cursors for the inserts. I know, I have not close the statements. If I close them, everything goes well.

The question is, why does Oracle create cursors for insert actions?

When I execute a `SELECT`, Oracle give a `ResultSet` back. I've tried to close the result sets but not the underlying statements. In this case (without inserts), the problem never occurs.

Comment: **Every** statement is executed through a "cursor". I'm pretty sure you are not properly closing your Statement instances (using `Statement.close()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every statement in Oracle is a cursor. Cursors in Oracle are meant to be reused by the client. If the client has no use for a cursor anymore, the client is responsible with closing the cursor.

In java you should almost always use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Forget about regular [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html), there is almost no reason to use them.

With `PreparedStatement` you parse once and execute as many time as you want:

1. [prepareStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29)
2. [bind](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29) as many times as there are variables
3. [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29)
4. repeat 2-3 until done, then close.

Alternatively, if you want to limit the DB roundtrips, you could:

1. [prepareStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29)
2. [bind](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29) as many times as there are variables
3. [addBatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)
4. repeat 2-3 until done, then [executeBatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29)
5. close the cursor

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a `Statement` if you are executing a SQL without parameters or only once.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is almost never a sql statement without parameters or variables. When you see a Statement in java, you are much more likely to see the product of an ugly string concatenation than a good use of the object. That's why it would be better to forget about the class entirely and pretend it does not exist =)

Answer (score 0):

you should ALWAYS close database resources you no longer use, and reuse those you can while they are open.
Anything else will eventually lead to resource exhaustion on the database, with ugly crashes as a result.